# useEffect is always running in React js (firebase firestore is used)

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks, use-effect

```
  const [bag, setBag] = useState([]);

  const bagRef = collection(db, "users", auth.currentUser.email, "bag");

  const updateBag = () => {
    onSnapshot(bagRef, (snapshot) => {
      // ...
      setBag(
        snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
          id: doc.id,
          data: doc.data(),
        }))
      );
      console.log("run");
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    updateBag();
  }, []);
```

my problem is that the useEffect is always running, i can see that since 'run' is showing in my console, and my firestore usage is increasing tried passing different arguments in '[]' such as bag, bagRef, auth.currentUser.email and it didn't work. thx in advanced :)

Comment: The `console.log("run");` is in the `onSnapshot()` that triggers the callback whenever a document in bag sub-collection is added/updated/removed. So it could be that as well.

Comment: it worked just fine when i stopped the terminal then made it run, but thanks since when i moved the ```console.log( )``` outside the ```onSnapshot( )```  i get it reduced by 2/3 in the console

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?  I found this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71791900/16531380) that you can check if this would clarify your issues on your end.